# Reduce distance betwen bar groups in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I am using `pgfplots` and `groupplot` to create grouped bar plots, however the results  I get show both groups far from each other, the bars are too thin, and the whole figure doesn't look very elegant.

Is there a way to reduce the space between bar groups, and make the bars reasonably bigger?

Here is the code I have been using:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size = 1 by 3},
/pgf/bar width=4.8pt, 
symbolic x coords={AlgoEM, AlgoSL},
ybar=0.1pt,
enlarge x limits=0.2,
ymin=0,
xtick=data,
]

\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,1.5) (AlgoSL,0.8)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,1.5) (AlgoSL,0.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,1.9) (AlgoSL,0.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,1.5) (AlgoSL,0.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,2.3) (AlgoSL,0.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,4.2) (AlgoSL,0.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,4.4) (AlgoSL,0.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,2.0) (AlgoSL,1.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,83.6) (AlgoSL,1.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,17.3) (AlgoSL,0.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,0.8) (AlgoSL,0.0)};
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,2.6) (AlgoSL,1.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,2.9) (AlgoSL,1.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,3.0) (AlgoSL,2.0)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,1.4) (AlgoSL,1.4)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,2.5) (AlgoSL,1.1)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,6.6) (AlgoSL,1.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,7.0) (AlgoSL,1.9)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,3.0) (AlgoSL,2.0)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,82.1) (AlgoSL,3.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,0.5) (AlgoSL,0.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,0.4) (AlgoSL,0.1)};
\nextgroupplot[]
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,20.4) (AlgoSL,13.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,18.4) (AlgoSL,13.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,15.0) (AlgoSL,13.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,24.9) (AlgoSL,11.8)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,34.0) (AlgoSL,12.0)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,26.1) (AlgoSL,13.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,15.0) (AlgoSL,13.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,15.0) (AlgoSL,14.0)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,71.3) (AlgoSL,29.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,31.1) (AlgoSL,3.90)};
\addplot coordinates {(AlgoEM,8.70) (AlgoSL,0.00)};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with following settings of `groupplot`:

```
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size = 1 by 3},
height=55mm, width=88mm,% <---
/pgf/bar width=10pt,% <---
symbolic x coords={AlgoEM, AlgoSL},
ybar=0.1pt,
enlarge x limits=0.5,% <---
ymin=0,
xtick=data,
scale only axis,% <---
]
```

this gives:

[image]

off-topic:

`mathtools` call `amsmath`, `pgfplots` call `tikz`. instead of `compat=newest` is better to use version in which the plots is draw. so you can write your preamble as:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to make the whole plot wider? The plots are square, and if I put them together like this I will leave a lot of horizontal space.

Comment: you can prescribe diagrams' widths and heights with for example ` height=55mm, width=88mm,`. see edited answer